# Absolute Centered images not displaying in Firefox

Tags: html, css

This is my first comprehensive site that I've built, so I apologize if I'm missing anything obvious.

I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center an image of variable height and width in a container that also has a variable height. This is so the client can replace the image or make changes to the content in the adjacent div which ultimately controls the height.

I'm using absolute centering, described in [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/#Height) as well as others it references.

It's working beautifully in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox is not displaying the images. After endless tinkering and searching for the problem, I'm throwing my hands up. I know there are other solutions to vertical centering, but this seems to be the only one that can handle the variability of most elements involved.

Any suggested css/html changes to make this work would be GREATLY appreciated. The actual site where this is happening is [here](http://www.bangsshoes.com/our-partners/).

```
<div class="partner_section">
        <div class="partner_details">
            <div class="span_2 float-right">
                <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <p>content</p>
                <h4>Heading</h4>
                    <p>Content</p>
                <div class="partner_cta">
                    <a href="/canvas-shoes/black/">CTA</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span_2 float-left pImageContainer">
                <a href="http://springboardcollaborative.org/"><img class="" alt="SpringBoard Logo" src="/templates/__custom/images/custom/sblogo.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

---

```
 .partner_section {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   padding: 40px 0 40px 0;
   z-index: 100;
 }

 .partner_details {
   overflow: auto;
   width: 980px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   display: table;
  }

 .pImageContainer {
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
  }

 .pImageContainer img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
 }

 .span_2 {
    width: 49%;
 }

 .float-right {
    float: right;
 }

 .float-left {
    float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, the error is with `height: 100%` and `overflow: auto` on `.pImageContainer`. Because the item inside is `position: absolute`, the container is collapsing to 0 height and the item is hidden.

Removing `overflow: auto` just allows the image to be seen, but the container is not the correct height, hence why it isn't actually centered.

If you declare a firm height on any of the containers (`250px` for example), then it works correctly because `height: 100%` then has a correct value.

Alternatively, you can give `.pImageContainer` a `min-height` value to ensure that the image is always shown and centered within that area.

**Example:** http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/lFbHs

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and your help. Makes total sense and solved my issue! Cheers.

Comment: No problem! Firefox probably shouldn't behave that way, but it is. I tried a few other fixes, but nothing other than setting a fixed height worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `overflow: auto;` from `.pImageContainer {}`

I'm trying to research why that's causing the issue but coming up short at the moment.

That'll fix it though.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the overflow also causes the image to hug the top of the container : /